# Can't use a network CD-ROM

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, optical-drive, compact-disc

I have a computer with Windows XP and I'm trying to use my local network to use the CD-ROM of my notebook with Windows 7.

On the Windows XP computer with VLC I can open the menu of the DVD, but after choosing the option for the first chapter the movie window shuts down (but VLC stays open).

With BS-Player when trying to start the first chapter it freezes...

Is this possible to fix?